# Выбрать id строки, где максимальная дата создания и максимальная дата изменения

Tags: sql

| id | Дата создания | Дата изменения |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31.01.2023 | 31.01.2023 15:46 |
| 2 | 29.12.2022 | 31.01.2023 16:00 |
| 3 | 31.01.2023 | 31.01.2023 15:30 |

В таблице две строки с максимальной датой создания (31.01.2023) из них мне нужно получить id строки, где максимальная дата изменения (31.01.2023 15:46). Запрос должен вернуть id = 1.

Приведенный ниже запрос очевидно нерабочий! Какой диалект sql используется в базе не знаю, но GREATEST не поддерживается.

```
select id from table
where дата_создания = (select max(дата_создания) from table)
and дата_изменения = (select max(дата_изменения) from table)
```

Comment: `order by x desc, y desc limit 1`

Comment: Спасибо! Только в моём случае (в Firebirde)  select first 1 вместо limit.

Comment: Указывайте метку конкретной БД, если вам нужен ответ именно по ней )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, max(Дата изменения)   FROM table WHERE Дата создания in (SELECT MAX(Дата создания) FROM table) group by id
```

Comment: там id скорее всего автоинкрементный ключ, не надо по нему группировать.

Comment: Да. Нужен был конкретный id документа, так как с ним связаны нужные мне строки в другой таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Вернет верный результат при стремящейся к нулю вероятности дубля по дате изменения.

```
select first 1 id from table
order by дата_создания desc, дата_изменения desc
```